# save image with camera without compress image

Tags: c#, android, camera

In my application ,I want to take pictures with the camera and save them in a file.
Photo quality is very important in my application so When I compress to save it the image quality is lost.
this is my code:

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
       base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
       saveFullImage();
       if ((requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE))
       {

           if (data != null)
           {
               if (data.HasExtra("data"))
               { 
                   Bitmap pic = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");



                   System.IO.MemoryStream baos = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                   pic.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, baos);
                   byte[] byte_img_data = baos.ToArray();
                   outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileUri.Path);

                   outStream.Write(byte_img_data);
                   outStream.Close();



               }
           }
       }
    }
```

please help me.
thanks.

Comment: will you please post these two images: pre compress and post compress for others to tell how much the quality loss are?

Comment: Original image with camera is sized 789 kb but when I compress it to 77 kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all.

Using the following code does not change the picture details:

```
var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
var contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file);
mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
this.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pic.Save("yourfilenamehere.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

should be enough if you know you write on a file (check the Image class Save methods for other overloads).

This compression is lossless so you shouldn't lose any detail this way.